# Is it ok to store pointer to a child class in a container to a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a container:

```
QSet < QDialog*> dialogs_;
```

And I have few Dialogs which inherit from QDialog, so for example:

```
class _1_Dialog : public QDialog, private Ui::_1_Dialog
{};  
class _2_Dialog : public QDialog, private Ui::_1_Dialog
{};
```

and I'd like to store pointers to those dialogs in my 'dialogs_' member var. But now I'm getting error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'QDialog*' to '_1_Dialog*' [-fpermissive]
```

Would it be ok to use -fpermissive in that case or is this a bad idea?
EDIT:
I have a fnc called create_ and inside of its body I have a statement:

```
    template<class Dialog,class Caller, class Parent>
Dialog* Main_Dialog::create_(Caller* caller, Parent* parent)
{
    return (*dialogs_->insert(new Dialog(caller,parent)));
}
```

so this is the line
 which gives me the aforementioned error

Comment: Just FYI, names startig with `_` are reserved for the compiler. You will probably never experience a problem, but it's technically incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisLutz thanks, yes, I'm aware of this, this is just from my "practise box" - will never use outside of it. Thanks again. +1

Comment: How are you storing objects of type _1_Dialog?

Comment: In which line you get the error?

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. Is `dialogs_` declared as `Qset**`?

Comment: I dont see your class named "Dialog" whose instance you are creating  or have you omitted it in the question ?

Comment: @ChrisLutz: That's somewhat of a simplification. There's nothing wrong with `_1_Dialog` as part of the `Ui` namespace as `1` isn't an upper case letter. If `_2_Dialog` is, as it appears to be, at the global namespace scope, then that would be an issue.

Comment: Show us how this "create_" function is getting called ?

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Macros don't have namespaces, so not even `_1_Dialog` is fully safe.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Have I missed something, what makes you think that `_1_Dialog` has been defined as a macro?

Comment: @CharlesBailey - It hasn't been here, but the standard reserves the name for the compiler, which could define it as a macro in any of the standard headers.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: No, that would be non-conforming. Just as programs can't use names reserved for the implementation, the implementation is not allowed to use names reserved for the program. names starting with a leading underscore followed by something other than an upper case letter, not containing a double underscore are reserved for the program everywhere other than at global namespace scope.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Ah. I'm used to C and the rules are more complicated in C++, so whenever I get a bit fuzzy on the rules I generally assume the worst case version to be safe. My bad.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I'd certainly agree that it's better to err on the side of safety.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* store pointers to derived classes in containers holding base classes. However, what you get out of it is a pointer to the base class. You would then, usually, either only use the base class methods, or use dynamic_cast to check what its type really is.

```
template<class Dialog,class Caller, class Parent>
Dialog* Main_Dialog::create_(Caller* caller, Parent* parent)
{
    return (*dialogs_->insert(new Dialog(caller,parent)));
}
```

*dialogs_->insert() is a pointer to a base class. *You* know that it will always point to a class Dialog, but the compiler does not, because you never told it. Try this:

```
template<class Dialog,class Caller, class Parent>
Dialog* Main_Dialog::create_(Caller* caller, Parent* parent)
{
    Dialog* result = new Dialog(caller,parent);
    dialogs_->insert(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But i'd like to note, that it may be a typo and TS wanted to return `QDialog` from `create_`, not dialog.

Comment: @hvd am afraid, it doesn't make any difference. Either -fpermissive or no go.

Comment: Good point. I would expect `Main_Dialog.create_<Dialog1, Caller, Parent>(caller, parent)` to return a `Dialog1*`, but if `Dialog1` provides no public members that are meaningful to the caller, that adds no value over returning a `QDialog`.

Comment: @user336635 Do you get the exact same error? In the code you posted, there is an implicit conversion from QDialog* to Dialog*, and that's the one I took out. Does it now give a subtly different error, or the exact same one? And on which line?

Comment: @user336635, you should return `interface` but hide `realization`. So, if your dialog interface is that it is `QDialog`, you should return `QDialog`

Comment: @user336635 No, I split your one line into three lines. On which of those three lines does it now give an error?

Comment: @Lol4t0 I'm not sure I agree. If Dialog1 has a member `AddButton()`, it makes sense to be able to do `dialog = create<Dialog1>(); dialog.AddButton();` The caller already explicitly specified a Dialog1 is what is to be created. You should return interfaces when you want to promise no more than that, and in this case, `create_<Dialog1>()` surely does promise more than that.

Comment: @hvd, in that case dialog `interface` _is not_ `QDialog`. And function, that uses `create_` can be `template` function as well, that's why there is no sure about promises

Comment: @Lol4t0 In that case I misunderstood what you were saying, and I agree. If you want the caller to not call anything other than the base `QDialog` methods, then yes, return a `QDialog`. I misread and missed the "if".

Comment: @user336635 Considering there is no `conversion from 'QDialog*' to '_1_Dialog*'` on line 2, that seems strange. Are you sure the error message didn't change? If you're getting `conversion from '_1_Dialog*' to 'QDialog*'` now, I could see that happening: it could mean you're instantiating the template with Ui::_1_Dialog instead of the _1_Dialog you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code inside function:

```
return (*dialogs_->insert(new Dialog(caller,parent)));
        ^ // Returning Base class pointer
```

And your return type is of `Dialog *`

Hence there is a casting done from `Base TO Derived` and implicit casting fails here.

Try `dynamic_cast` to Dialog pointer (from QDialog pointer) and then return.

Comment: @OP: is your class templated or member funtion ? you should mention that too

Comment: You're assuming `Main_Dialog` is a templated class. I'm guessing `Main_Dialog` isn't, only its `create_` function is templated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not (yet) tried to write any code specific to your problem, but from the architectural point, your situations it's the most common and obvious application of OOP to GUI: any Widget (for instance) it's a container of Widgets (i.e. the base class of some more specific GUI element)...

What's strange to me, why you derive from 2 classes, one public (ok) and a private (may a dialog related) also?

BTW I think that's it's the private part that cause your error: try to change to public.